# Add button to grid in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, grid

I'm very new with **ExtJS**.

Does any one know how to add button to each row of grid in **ExtJS**?

Please give me some example.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can check it out here, hope it helps!

http://techmix.net/blog/2010/11/25/add-button-to-extjs-gridpanel-cell-using-renderer/

Answer (score 6):

Actualy Ext.Buttons in a row cell is as far as i can tell impossible with the current setup of Ext. Ofcourse it is actually possible to render the HTML of a button in the div of the cell but i actually think that would be a bad idea.

A better way is to implement Saki's rowactions plugin which makes it really easy to add buttons/actions to each row.

http://rowactions.extjs.eu/

Answer (score 5):

you should use a custom renderer but I advice you to use a toolbar button instead more clean.

If you wanna have more reference here come the [documentation](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.ColumnModel) of the ColumnModel class.

anyway it would give something like that

```
 var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
     store: store,
     columns: [{
         id: 'company',
         header: 'Company',
         width: 160,
         sortable: true,
         dataIndex: 'company'
     }, {
         header: 'Price',
         width: 75,
         sortable: true,
         renderer: 'usMoney',
         dataIndex: 'price'
     }, {
         header: 'Change',
         width: 75,
         sortable: true,
         renderer: change,
         dataIndex: 'change'
     }, {
         header: '% Change',
         width: 75,
         sortable: true,
         renderer: pctChange,
         dataIndex: 'pctChange'
     }, {
         header: 'Last Updated',
         width: 85,
         sortable: true,
         renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
         dataIndex: 'lastChange'
     }, {
         header: 'action',
         width: 85,
         sortable: false,
         renderer: function(val) {
             return '<input type="button" value="toto" id="' + val + '"/>';
         },
         dataIndex: 'somefieldofyourstore'
     }],
     stripeRows: true,
     autoExpandColumn: 'company',
     height: 350,
     width: 600,
     title: 'Array Grid',
     // config options for stateful behavior
     stateful: true,
     stateId: 'grid'
 });
```

This snippet is an extract of [this sample](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html).

For the toolbar way I advice you, just add a button to the toolbar of the [GridPanel](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel) and hook the [SelectionModel](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel) so you can disable the buttons when the user doesn't select any row.

Comment: @bensui: I believe in case of the a list you have to provide the template to create the markup anyway, so yes...

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this code for adding button as image in your grid here is code :

```
new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    header: "Action",
    items: [{
        icon: '../images/enable.png',
        tooltip: 'Enable App',
        width: 50,
        id: 'enableAppId',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex) {
            //add code for button click
        }
    }]
}]);
```

I have also use this for enable the row data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna add an extra answer to this question because since this question has been posted i've created an extension for the ExtJS grid component that allows buttons to be added to grid columns.

https://github.com/Inventis/Ext.ux.grid.ButtonColumn

Just be aware that it might affect performance on older/slower systems when rendering a large amount of rows.